# how to check if Option is None in Scala

Tags: scala

I have following code, the return from Database could be a single record or nothing, once I get the database return, i check it , if it has a `record(EmailStatus object)`, i convert it to a list of single EmailStatus object, otherwise return a list of default `EmailStatus` object,

```
database
      .getLatestEmailStatusByEmail(email)
      .map(
        emailStatusDTO =>
          if (emailStatusDTO == None) List(emailStatusDTO.default(email))
          else List(emailStatusDTO)
      )
      .leftMap[HttpError] {
        case e =>
          logger.error(LoggingMessage(
            requestId,
            s"Retrieve events by ${email} failed, ${e.getClass.getSimpleName} : ${e.message}"))
          DatabaseError(e.message, requestId)
      }
```

but it complaint:

```
comparing case class values of types .core.dto.EmailStatusDTO and None.type using `==' will always yield false
          if (emailStatusDTO == None)
```

the type of return from DB :

```
database.getLatestEmailStatusByEmail(email)
```

is

```
type ServiceResult[Err, A] = EitherT[Future, Err, A]
def apply[A](a: Future[Option[A]], error: Err)(
        implicit ec: ExecutionContext): ServiceResult[Err, A] =
      EitherT(a map (data => Either.fromOption(data, error)))
  }
```

and `EmailStatus` is a case class.

so in my case it will return `Future[Option[EmailStatusDto]]` so how can i check if the database return is None?

also changed the check to `isEmpty`, it didn't work either:

`if (emailStatusDTO.isEmpty) List(EmailStatusDTO.normal(email.email))`

`if (emailStatusDTO.isEmpty()) List(EmailStatusDTO.normal(email.email))`
it said 'cannot resolve symbol isEmpty`

Comment: looks like you believe `emailStatusDTO` type is `Option[EmailStatus]` but that compiler error says it is `.core.dto.EmailStatusDTO`

Comment: When you do have an `Option`, use the [`.isEmpty`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#isEmpty:Boolean) method.

Comment: @TravisHegner, it didn't work with isEmpty either, updated my post

Comment: @Gustek, that's a typo, updated my post

Comment: Add type ascription `emailStatusDTO :Option[EmailStatusDto] =>` to see if the compiler agrees with your assumptions.

Comment: @user468587 Gustek's point wasn't about the missing `DTO`. It was about the fact that you say that it's an option, but the compiler says it's not (and the compiler is always right).